# useHistory() push to path re-renders error page instead of going to page

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-router-dom, browser-history

I'm using react, react-router and graphQL (Apollo). If there is a mutation error, I have it set up with an `<Error error={mutationError} />` component that drills down to the specific error. I'm trying to implement an `back` button use the `useHistory()` hook with `<Button onClick={() => history.push(history.location.pathname)} text="Back" />`

Instead of returning to the specific update form (example route: `http://www.ourDomain.com/customers/545kkkfd/updateForm`), it stays on the error page. Is there a better hook or api to go back? Do I need to reset something?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but normally you can go back easily enough with history.goBack()

Answer (score 0):

`history.push(history.location.pathname)` will just push the current location. Even though you are accessing a `location` object from the `history` object it is still the current matched location.

If you are wanting to do a back navigation then use one of the following:

- `history.goBack()`
- `history.go(-1)`